# Error in JFreeChart stacked horizontal bar chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Why does this code:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset datasetE = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
datasetE.addValue(0.5, "HOLDING", "NOME 1");
datasetE.addValue(0.7, "HOLDING", "NOME 2");
datasetE.addValue(0.1, "HEATING", "NOME 3");
datasetE.addValue(0.5, "HEATING", "NOME 4");
datasetE.addValue(0.8, "HEATING", "NOME 5");
                
JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart("Stacked Bar Chart Demo 1", "Category", "Value", datasetE, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);   
jfreechart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);   
CategoryPlot categoryplot = (CategoryPlot)jfreechart.getPlot();   
categoryplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);   
categoryplot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);   
StackedBarRenderer stackedbarrenderer = (StackedBarRenderer)categoryplot.getRenderer();   
stackedbarrenderer.setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0, new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());   
stackedbarrenderer.setSeriesVisible(0, true);
ChartPanel CPProgesterona = new ChartPanel(jfreechart,400,80,400,80,400,80,false,false,false,false,false,false); panel2.add(CPProgesterona,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

return this:

[image]

Comment: what was the purpose of the code? which part is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I wanted to draw stacked bars, the first one goes from 0.5 the second one from 0.5 to 0.7 and so on.

The chart is not rendered at all!

Comment: on your title you said you're trying to add it as `horizontal`. and still inside the code I see you're adding it as `vertical`

Comment: I changed the code to: JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart("Stacked Bar Chart Demo 1", "Category", "Value", datasetE, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, false);  

but the problem remains.

What can I do?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset has two series, each with a distinct row key; but it has five distinct categories, each with one of five distinct column keys. You probably want two series, *each* having its own set of distinct column keys.

[image: stacked bar chart]

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.addValue(0.5, "HOLDING", "NAME 1");
dataset.addValue(0.7, "HOLDING", "NAME 2");
dataset.addValue(0.1, "HEATING", "NAME 1");
dataset.addValue(0.5, "HEATING", "NAME 2");
dataset.addValue(0.8, "HEATING", "NAME 3");
JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
    "Stacked Bar Chart", "Category", "Value", dataset,
    PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, false);
CategoryPlot categoryplot = (CategoryPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
categoryplot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
categoryplot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
StackedBarRenderer stackedbarrenderer = (StackedBarRenderer) categoryplot.getRenderer();
stackedbarrenderer.setDefaultItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
stackedbarrenderer.setDefaultItemLabelsVisible(true);
```