# Categorzing values and changing color based on condition in StackedBarChart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am working in JasperStudio and customizing a **StackedBarChart** to show it values like this.
[image: required result]
I have written the below code

```
static class CustomBarRenderer extends BarRenderer {
    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomBarRenderer() {
        super();
    }

    public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int column) {
        Color color = null;
        CategoryDataset cd = getPlot().getDataset();
    
        if (cd != null) {
            String l_rowKey = (String) cd.getRowKey(row);
            String l_colKey = (String) cd.getColumnKey(column);
            double l_value = cd.getValue(l_rowKey, l_colKey).doubleValue();
            if (l_value < 70) {// red
                color = new Color(231, 104, 110);
            } // yellow
            else if (l_value >= 70 && l_value <= 90) {
                color = new Color(255, 190, 6);
            }
            //green
            else if (l_value > 90) {
                color = new Color(5, 176, 76);
            }

        }
        return color;
    }
}
```

and called it using:

```
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jrChart) {
    CustomBarRenderer renderer = new CustomBarRenderer();
    chart.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(renderer);}
```

but it produces the following output which is totally strange to me. it creates separate bars whereas I want the results on the same bar. Is there any way I could get it stacked fulfilling the above conditions? Thanks

[image: current result]

If I try this code, It doesn't produce the seprate bars but doesn't categories the results.

```
 CategoryPlot cplot = (CategoryPlot)chart.getPlot();

 //set bar chart color

 ((BarRenderer)cplot.getRenderer()).setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());

 BarRenderer r = (BarRenderer)chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
 r.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(231,104,110)); r.setSeriesPaint(1, new
 Color(255,190,6)); r.setSeriesPaint(2, new Color(5,176,76));
```

I am having three category series in my chart in Jasper report
[image]
Here is a sample from my dataset. I just made a dummy. It might be wrong. How should I manage it? thanks
[image]

Comment: I think the problem is in your dataset; there's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63668455/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I updated the question and included a data set. Please have a look

Comment: Yes, you'll need one of the three keys shown in column D for each category; I don't know how [tag:jasper-reports] maps your dataset to an `org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset`.